# postgresql trigger (strategy) to update table based on entries of another table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am fairly new to PostgreSQL (spoilt by django ORM!), and I would like to create a trigger which updates a table based on entries of another table.

So, I have the following table on my schema:

```
collection_myblogs(id, col1,col2,title,col4,col5)
```

..where field `id` is autogenerated. Now, I have a new table created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE FullText(id SERIAL NOT NULL, content text NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE ONLY FullText ADD CONSTRAINT fulltext_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

and I insert values from collection_myblogs like so:

```
INSERT INTO FullText(content) SELECT title FROM collection_myblogs;
```

All fine so far...I would now like a trigger on `FullText` such that `FullText` updates itself with new entries everytime collection_myblogs has a new entry. So, I attempted creating a trigger as following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER collection_ft_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON collection_myblogs FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ft_update();
```

Now, I am not entirely sure what should go on `ft_update()` function, and at the moment, I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ft_update() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FullText(content) SELECT new.title;
return new;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

..which works fine for `INSERTS` but not `UPDATES`. i.e if I update the title of the orginal column `collections_myblog(title)` it appears as a new entry on `FullText` I am unsure how to deal with `ids` here.

I would like the `ids` i.e primary keys to be the same on each table. So, the idea for me is to have `FullText(id, content) == collection_myblogs(id, title)` - if this makes sense. So, the `id` and the `content` should be replicated from `collection_myblogs` table. How would one go about achieving this?

My understanding is that I can use a trigger before any insert or an update on my `collection_myblogs` and `somehow` maintain `FullText(id, content) == collection_myblogs(id, title)`

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a large number of ways to handle this problem.  Some examples:

1. Use table inheritance to create an "interface" to your data (no trigger needed, the abstract table ends up functioning like a view). This is complicated territory though.
2. Use the trigger approach like you do and then handle UPDATE and DELETE separately.  The big issue here is that if you have two areas of text that are identical, your update trigger needs to be able to separate them.

There are many others but those should get you started.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it turned out to be quite simple. Just had to follow [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)